# How to compile cairo in ios platform

Tags: ios, compilation, cairo

I'm working a lot with Cairo on MacOSX/Windows and decided to port one of my projects to iPhone as well. I use the following method to compile pixman

./configure clang="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -std=c99 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/" AR="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"

and the following method to compile cairo

./configure clang="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -std=gnu99 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=8.1" AR="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar"
--enable-xlib=no --enable-xlib-xrender=no --enable-ft=no --enable-script=no --enable-ps=no --enable-pdf=no --enable-svg=no --enable-trace=no --enable-interpreter=no --enable-png=no

Both succeed,but when I use libcairo.a and libpixman.a in project.one error came out:
 ld:targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables in __pixman_implementation_lookup_composite for architecture x86_64
clang:error:linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

And I don't have a clue.

Does anything one had succeed compile cairo in IOS platforms? please help!

Comment: As I compile both cairo and pixman again. when I use this two new .a file,while Linking ,two error came out                                                   undef:  __pixman_add_triangles                                                                                    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Comment: ld:symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64                                                       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

In short, you're just building for x86. As your emulator requires x64, it couldn't link the required libraries. To make a functioning library, you also need to compile armv7, armv7s, arm64 to run on devices.

I have tried to build cairo with its many dependencies on all these architectures a while ago, but i couldn't get the text to dislplay correctly. The stokes are fine though.

Comment: Update: Together with Pango, I can render texts onto cairo as strokes to draw on the surface. To get the app posted to appstore, you'll need to patch cairo here and there to get rid of the private apis.